# Mozilla extension issue developing using AngularJS 1

Tags: angularjs

When using the `AngularJS` to create mozilla browser extension, when requesting for the service call using `$http` that time when response come an error encountered.

This is what I was getting when I am requesting using `$http` :

> Error: 'setTimeout' called on an object that does not implement
>   interface Window.

```
Browser/self.defer@resource://gre/modules/ExtensionContent.jsm -> moz-extension://cb6087c3-cd93-43d0-b239-0681ece93f36/dotAlign_Project/app/lib/angular/angular.js:6241:17
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$evalAsync@resource://gre/modules/ExtensionContent.jsm -> moz-extension://cb6087c3-cd93-43d0-b239-0681ece93f36/dotAlign_Project/app/lib/angular/angular.js:17719:11
$QProvider/this.$get</<@resource://gre/modules/ExtensionContent.jsm -> moz-extension://cb6087c3-cd93-43d0-b239-0681ece93f36/dotAlign_Project/app/lib/angular/angular.js:16291:7
scheduleProcessQueue@resource://gre/modules/ExtensionContent.jsm -> moz-extension://cb6087c3-cd93-43d0-b239-0681ece93f36/dotAlign_Project/app/lib/angular/angular.js:16399:5
qFactory/<.$$resolve@resource://gre/modules/ExtensionContent.jsm -> moz-extension://cb6087c3-cd93-43d0-b239-0681ece93f36/dotAlign_Project/app/lib/angular/angular.js:16432:11
qFactory/<.resolve@resource://gre/modules/ExtensionContent.jsm -> moz-extension://cb6087c3-cd93-43d0-b239-0681ece93f36/dotAlign_Project/app/lib/angular/angular.js:16415:9
simpleBind/<@resource://gre/modules/ExtensionContent.jsm -> moz-extension://cb6087c3-cd93-43d0-b239-0681ece93f36/dotAlign_Project/app/lib/angular/angular.js:16368:7
resolvePromise@resource://gre/modules/ExtensionContent.jsm -> moz-extension://cb6087c3-cd93-43d0-b239-0681ece93f36/dotAlign_Project/app/lib/angular/angular.js:11843:10
resolveHttpPromise@resource://gre/modules/ExtensionContent.jsm -> moz-extension://cb6087c3-cd93-43d0-b239-0681ece93f36/dotAlign_Project/app/lib/angular/angular.js:11824:11
done@resource://gre/modules/ExtensionContent.jsm -> moz-extension://cb6087c3-cd93-43d0-b239-0681ece93f36/dotAlign_Project/app/lib/angular/angular.js:11830:11
completeRequest@resource://gre/modules/ExtensionContent.jsm -> moz-extension://cb6087c3-cd93-43d0-b239-0681ece93f36/dotAlign_Project/app/lib/angular/angular.js:12033:7
requestLoaded@resource://gre/modules/ExtensionContent.jsm -> moz-extension://cb6087c3-cd93-43d0-b239-0681ece93f36/dotAlign_Project/app/lib/angular/angular.js:11966:9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the reason of the problem, 
Due to use **'window'** object in the **'Angular Library'** this error was coming.
So to solve the issue I replaced **'window'** object with **'$window'**.